# Edge detection in C++ without fopen

Tags: c++, image-processing

I want write a code in C++ to find edges in an image. in this code for reading data i have to use fopen function, also for writing results to the file.
Anybody can to tell me how can i write this code without use the fopen function?
for example a small image with 30x30 size, data's stored in a constant and the edge operation done on it and after that the results stored to the other constant.

excuse my poor English.

Comment: Is your data stored in an array in the program, and you want to store the result in another array? Or is the image data in a file, but you just don't want to use C file handling functions like `fopen`?

Comment: You're question isn't very clear. Are you using a library that forces you to use `fopen` somehow? If so, what library and what specific APIs are you making? If you're writing the code, what exactly is your problem with using a chunk of memory rather than a file? Please be much more specific and show the code that's problematic.

Comment: If the image is a constant, you can just store the edge-detected result as constant instead, so from that point of view, it doesn't make much sense. I would go with the approach suggested by @geert3 if anything else is desired, this lets you pipe anything into your program trivially.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know why you don't want to use `fopen` but you can use `stdin` and `stdout`; these are `FILE*` that are always open for you. You can then run the program like this:

```
yourprog.exe < inputfile > outputfile
```

Reading `stdin` will read data from `inputfile`. Writing to `stdout` will write into `outputfile`.

Comment: As we're talking about c++ you should rather mention `std::cin` and `std::cout` and how to use `std::istream`, `std::ostream`